# Inserted records getting committed in DB without committing it manually

Tags: database, transactions, h2db

I have created a database transaction and I am inserting records in `Table1` of `H2` DB. But no commits done yet.
In between this process, after executing half of the records, I execute one `create` statement(created Table2).

`Table2` is created and along with it, previous `INSERT` statements are also getting committed in DB.

After this, I'm inserting more records in `Table1`, if there is a failure in insertion, I still see records in Table1 which were inserted before `create` statement for `Table2`.

Due to this, I see some records in DB even after transaction failure. I was expecting ZERO records in DB.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `create table` is a DDL statement and no DML statement. And DDL statement usually commit any open transaction.

If you want to avoid this you should create all objects you need during the import before you import the first record.

**EDIT 2019-03-22**

Although this topic is a bit old I like to mention one thing which could help. You could create a procedure which uses `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` which executes an sql statement via `execute immediate`

```
PROCEDURE exec_sql_autonomous(p_sql VARCHAR2)
AS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_sql;

   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
END;
```

This way you may be able to create a table while the data inserting transaction is in progress without committing it due to the table creation.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this? I want to delay table creation as mush as possible. So if there are entries for that table and we need it then only we create the table.

Comment: Docs say about CREATE TABLE: "This command commits an open transaction, except when using TRANSACTIONAL (only supported for temporary tables)."